# How to use H.map.Spatial.Label?

Tags: here-api

I am trying to figure out how [H.map.Spatial.Label](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.14.0/api_reference/H.map.Spatial.html#.Label) is used. The docs only ever reference the type on this page and it is not mentioned anywhere else.

My goal is to render a label on a H.map.Polygon object from the GeoJSON reader (without an SVG) and this seems like the closest type to use. I am able to style the polygon object with colors but I am finding it difficult to properly render a label.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below, create a dynamic label that keeps on getting different value from geoJSON field.

```
var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");
newlabel.setAttribute("for",id_from_input);
newlabel.innerHTML = "Here goes the text";
var icon = new H.map.Icon(newlabel);
var marker = new H.map.Marker({lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 }, {icon: icon});
map.addObject(marker);
```